# how to install plugin/head for elastic search?

Tags: elasticsearch, sense, elasticsearch-marvel

I have installed elastic search and its plugin head but when i enter the

```
 **url 
"localhost:9200/_plugin/head/"**
```

It does not shows any thing?

And I have also install marvel/SENSE for monitoring purpose.
I have installed plugin/head using

```
sudo elasticsearch/bin/plugin -install mobz/elasticsearch-head
```

But its also not working .
Error: console not found on url
http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/sense_widget.html?snippets/010_Intro/10_Info.json

BTW I am new to elastic search.
So if you could tell me why it is not showing anything or have i made any mistake.

Thank in advance!

Comment: When you run the command to install elasticsearch-head do you see a confirmation message that the plugin was installed? Also, can you see the `head` directory in `${ES_HOME}\plugins`?

Comment: I have found an extremely useful website that will guide you through the entire Linux stack installation:
[LinuxInstallGuide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-elasticsearch-logstash-and-kibana-4-on-ubuntu-14-04).

Another thought, what directory did you attempt the install?  Try installing by first changing the directory to %{ES_HOME}, and then attempting to install with "bin/plugin --install mobz/elasticsearch-head".

Answer (score 20):

If someone tries with version 5 or else:

- for Elasticsearch 5.x: plugins are not supported. Run elasticsearch-head as a standalone
- for Elasticsearch 2.x – 4.x:
  sudo elasticsearch/bin/plugin install mobz/elasticsearch-head
- for Elasticsearch 1.x:
  sudo elasticsearch/bin/plugin -install mobz/elasticsearch-head/1.x
- for Elasticsearch 0.9:
  sudo elasticsearch/bin/plugin -install mobz/elasticsearch-head/0.9

From [GitHub](https://github.com/mobz/elasticsearch-head)

Comment: How would on run elasticsearch-head as a stand alone?

Comment: @JpHouten There is  [Run as a standalone server](https://github.com/mobz/elasticsearch-head#running-with-built-in-server)

Answer (score 12):

I've just installed ES using 1.4.4. on windows. Please check if you've got the confirmation that the plugging is installed. Also double check your commands. See below.

[image]

Comment: For me it only worked without the dash: plugin.bat install mobz/elasticsearch-head

Comment: My command is "plugin install mobz/elasticsearch-head". Tested on Elasticsearch 2.2

Comment: For version 2.2 dash "-" before the word "install" is not required.

Comment: 'plugin' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. in elasticsearch 5.4.1

Answer (score 3):

The following are what I used on my Ubuntu 14.04 elasticsearch 2.0.0. 
instead of -i, you need to use the word **install** ( without dash )

with proxy:

```
/opt/elasticsearch/bin/plugin install -DproxyPort=80 -DproxyHost=www.example.com mobz/elasticsearch-head
```

without proxy:

```
/opt/elasticsearch/bin/plugin install mobz/elasticsearch-head
```

Answer (score 2):

Updating the already existing answers for CentOS/RHEL 7.

Since v5.x the ElasticSearch Head plugin [is deprecated](https://github.com/mobz/elasticsearch-head#running-with-built-in-server) and es-head must be run as a standalone server. Here's how to install on CentOS/RHEL 7.

First, [install Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/) and Git.

Then run these commands:

```
git clone git://github.com/mobz/elasticsearch-head.git
cd elasticsearch-head
npm install
npm run start
```

Assuming that your ES installation runs on http://localhost:9200/, you can now access es-head on http://localhost:9100/.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to use proxy to access external websites, you can the following command to install it:

```
bin/plugin -i -DproxyPort=80 -DproxyHost=www.example.com mobz/elasticsearch-head
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also run elastic-search head as a chrome extension "ElasticSearch Head". Click the extension icon in the toolbar of your web browser after installing.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Ubuntu 16.04 or any other version, This command will surely run,

elasticsearch/bin/plugin install -DproxyPort=80 -DproxyHost=www.example.com mobz/elasticsearch-head

Comment: What does this answer add over the one chad.zheng posted? They seem nearly identical to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can create systemd unit with npm run start. Like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Elasticsearch-head
After=syslog.target
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/npm run start
WorkingDirectory=/usr/share/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-head
Restart=always
StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog
User=user
Group=user

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```